# Help to prove this predicate

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Please help me to prove the following. 
Please explain step by step, I'm new to this subject.

For any non-empty set $S$ and for any two predicates $p$ defined on $S^2$, prove or disprove the following.

1. $∃x∃y\colon p(x,y) ⇔ ∃y∃x\colon p(x,y)$
2. $∃y∀x\colon p(x,y) \Rightarrow ∃y \colon p(x,y)$

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assunme $\exists x\exists y\colon p(x,y)$.
So let $x_0$ be such that $\exists y\colon p(x_0,y)$.
Now let $y_0$ be such that $p(x_0,y_0)$.
Hence $\exists x\colon p(x,y_0)$ and finally $\exists y\exists x\colon p(x,y)$.
The reverse direction follows likewise.

Assume $\exists y\forall x\colon p(x,y)$.
So let $y_0$ be such that $\forall x\colon p(x,y_0)$.
Then especially $p(x,y_0)$ and hence $\exists y\colon p(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
and there's some on that question...
for any non-empty set S, and for any two predicate p and q defined on S^2 and S respectively, prove the rest..
3)∀x in S ∃y in S p(x,y) ==> ∃y in S p(x,y)

Comment: 4)∀x in S q(x) ==> ∃x in S q(x)
5)∃x in S q(x) ==>∀x in S q(x)
  note that if there are wrong statements u hav to disprove them also
please help these too.. as I am new to this subject